# HDD error when mounting

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

When I plug in my external hard disk drive I get this error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdf1 at /media/makermex/Seagate Expansion Drive: 
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o 
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" 
"/dev/sdf1" "/media/makermex/Seagate Expansion Drive"' exited with non-zero exit status 18: Failed to open $MFT/$BITMAP: No such file or directory
Failed to load $MFT: No such file or directory
Failed to mount '/dev/sdf1': No such file or directory
```

I was looking for information about the error but I can't find anything, do you know how I can solve this please ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
     blkid
```

and this gives you some info, and this you can use in /etc/fstab

you can also do this:

```
     1 | greb -f $a1
```

and you can also use gparted from software-center.

Comment: I fix it with a laptop with windows, with the command chkdsk D: /f